# google plus login is redirecting to google.com in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, gmail, google-plus

I followed google developer docs to implement a simple google plus (gmail) sign in button in my basic app. But When i run the code it going to google.com.

So here are the steps i followed.

1.Created new client id and added that into app from google console.
2.Imported frameworks
3.When i run the code i can see

it first open google sign in page  then it will open Oauth page if i press "allow" access then it will redirect from "accounts.google.com" to "google.com.

I have created a sample project for that

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6caVk8MnBVabUctb1RybExJbTQ/view?usp=sharing) is my code  and screen shots[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

my file and framework list
[image]

CODE

AppDelegate.m

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation {
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];
}
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
@class GPPSignInButton;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<GPPSignInDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GPPSignInButton *signInButton;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
//
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>
#define kClientId @"49781846815-pbsb1vso4nrbes9a4al5kae2d98ie3cf.apps.googleusercontent.com"
#define kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize signInButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  // Uncomment to get the user's email

    // You previously set kClientId in the "Initialize the Google+ client" step
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;

    // Uncomment one of these two statements for the scope you chose in the previous step
    signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];  // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" scope
    signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];            // "profile" scope

    // Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"
    signIn.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error {
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
    if (error) {
        // Do some error handling here.
    } else {
        [self refreshInterfaceBasedOnSignIn];
    }
}
-(void)refreshInterfaceBasedOnSignIn {
    if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {
        // The user is signed in.
        NSLog(@"hi");
        self.signInButton.hidden = YES;
        // Perform other actions here, such as showing a sign-out button
    } else {
        self.signInButton.hidden = NO;
        // Perform other actions here
    }
}

- (void)presentSignInViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    // This is an example of how you can implement it if your app is navigation-based.
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Please help to clear this google.com redirect issue and also to develop a good login.

Comment: Is your application:openUrl:... method ever being called? Put a break point or some debug in there. If it's not being called, I have the same problem.

Comment: @ I have the same issue, but Im using the new Google SigIn library, and in my case it opens a webview inside the app, and when I try to accept the terms, it simply goes back to google.com.

Comment: Did anyone resolved this issue? I've suffering from same issue and still finding solution, any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2015, even if you got this working, your app would then be rejected by Apple's App Store review team because of a childish fight going on between Apple and Google. See this issue in the Google+ SDK: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900